# File `logol' not found. \end{document}

Tags: errors

I use the following template:
(I downloaded it from: https://www.amcs.uz.zgora.pl/?action=guide)

```
\documentclass{amcs}

\title{Instructions for authors on how to use the AMCS \LaTeX~class}

\author[ad1][ad2]{First name LAST NAME}
\author[ad1][]{Second AUTHOR}
%\author[ad1][ad2]{Third AUTHOR}
%\author[ad2][]{Fourth AUTHOR}
%\author[ad1][ad2]{Fifth AUTHOR}
%\author[ad2][]{Sixth AUTHOR}

%\correspondingauthor{Fifth AUTHOR}

\address[ad1]{Institute of xxx xxx xxx xxx\\ University of xxx xxx, Address xxx xxx xx xxx xxx\\ e-mail: \url{xxx xx xxx}}
\address[ad2]{Second affiliation}

%\authors{First name LAST NAME \!$^{a}$, Second AUTHOR \!$^{a, b,}$\thanks{Corresponding author}\,\,,\\ Third AUTHOR \!$^{b}$}
%\addresses{$^{a}$\! Institute of xxx xxx xxx xxx\\ University of xxx xxx, Address xxx xxx xx xxx xxx\\ e-mail: \url{xxx xx xxx}\\\medskip $^{b}$\! Second affiliation}

%\Runauthors{F. AUTHOR \it{et al.}}
%\Runauthors{J. DOE}
%\Runauthors{J. DOE and M. JOHN}

%Please do not remove these
%\Year{}
%\Vol{}
%\No{}
%\Startpage{}
%\Endpage{}
%\DOI{}
%\Received{10 May 2006}
%\Revised{24 October 2005}
%\Rerevised{15 December 2006}
%\Accepted{10 January 2007}

\bibliographystyle{dcu}

\begin{document}
First line\\
\indent Second line
\end{document}
```

I put all the relevant files in the right directory. However, when running it I get the error message: `File logol not found. \end{document}.`
Although I get the pdf file. Why is it?

Here is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.1.15)  30 OCT 2016 19:38
entering extended mode
**trial.tex
(trial.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
(amcs.cls
Document Style `amcs' <2016>.
Document Class: amcs 2016/05/06
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\times.sty"
Package: times 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen103
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count87
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count88
\leftroot@=\count89
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count90
\DOTSCASE@=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count92
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count93
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count94
\dspbrk@lvl=\count95
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count96
\column@=\count97
\maxfields@=\count98
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (caption2.sty
Package: caption2 2002/08/03 v2.1 Customising captions (AS)
\captionmargin=\dimen112
\captionwidth=\dimen113
\captionindent=\dimen114
Package caption2 Info: Running in caption2 v2.0 compatibility mode on input lin
e 147.
\captionlinewidth=\dimen115
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
Package: color 2014/10/28 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 137.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count99
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks19
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen116
\Gin@req@width=\dimen117
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (harvard.sty
Package: harvard 

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\latex2html\html.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"
Package: hobsub-generic 2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `infwarerr' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ltxcmds' (already loaded).
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty"
Package: auxhook 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen118
\Hy@linkcounter=\count100
\Hy@pagecounter=\count101

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count102

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg"
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4443.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4448.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4451.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4458.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4463.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4688.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count103

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip11
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5041.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen119
\Fld@menulength=\count104
\Field@Width=\dimen120
\Fld@charsize=\dimen121
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6295.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6300.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6303.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6310.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6315.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6320.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6325.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6365.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6369.
\Hy@abspage=\count105
\c@Item=\count106
\c@Hfootnote=\count107
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
File: hpdftex.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count108
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count109

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip46
)
Package: html 1999/07/19 v1.38 hypertext commands for latex2html (nd, hws, rrm)

\c@lpart=\count110
\c@lchapter=\count111
\c@chapter=\count112
\c@lsection=\count113
\c@lsubsection=\count114
\c@lsubsubsection=\count115
\c@lparagraph=\count116
\c@lsubparagraph=\count117
\c@lsubsubparagraph=\count118
\ptrfile=\write3
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\algorithms\algorithm.sty"
Package: algorithm 2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating enviro
nment

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\float\float.sty"
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count119
\float@exts=\toks20
\float@box=\box28
\@float@everytoks=\toks21
\@floatcapt=\box29
)
\@float@every@algorithm=\toks22
\c@algorithm=\count120
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\algorithms\algorithmic.sty"
Package: algorithmic 2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithmic'
\c@ALC@unique=\count121
\c@ALC@line=\count122
\c@ALC@rem=\count123
\c@ALC@depth=\count124
\ALC@tlm=\skip47
\algorithmicindent=\skip48
)
\c@author=\count125
\c@address=\count126
\abstractbox=\box30
\keywordbox=\box31
\dlugosc=\skip49
\c@theorem=\count127
\c@proposition=\count128
\c@lemma=\count129
\c@corollary=\count130
\c@example=\count131
\c@remark=\count132
\c@definition=\count133
\c@problem=\count134
\c@observation=\count135
\c@assumption=\count136
\c@property=\count137
\@npoints=\dimen122
\@nbrak=\count138
\@nlines=\count139
\@tekst=\count140
\c@appendix=\count141
)
(trial.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+ptm on input line 38.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1ptm.fd"
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count142
\scratchdimen=\dimen123
\scratchbox=\box32
\nofMPsegments=\count143
\nofMParguments=\count144
\everyMPshowfont=\toks23
\MPscratchCnt=\count145
\MPscratchDim=\dimen124
\MPnumerator=\count146
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count147
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks24
)
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box33
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 38.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count148
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 38.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 38.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 38.

(trial.out) (trial.out)
\@outlinefile=\write4
Package hyperref Info: *** compatibility with harvard ****  on input line 38.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 41.


! LaTeX Error: File `logol' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.41 \end{document}

I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 41.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 41.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd"
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
) [2{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}


]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 41.
 (trial.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 41.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 41.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `trial.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 41.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6844 strings out of 493698
 95334 string characters out of 3144421
 183838 words of memory out of 3000000
 10084 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 9079 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 51i,10n,28p,256b,319s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/fontname/8r.enc}<C:/Program File
s/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/font
s/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb>
Output written on trial.pdf (1 page, 13436 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 20 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 2 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: the zip file contains a logol.eps put it in the same directory as your document

Comment: All the ZIP files are at the directory, including logol.eps

Comment: well either you have a very old pdftex installation that can not automatically convert eps files or something else you have not told us is wrong.

Comment: I use the following: TeXstudio 2.11.2 (hg 6192:72f68414a729)
Using Qt Version 5.6.1, compiled with Qt 5.6.1 R. Other templates work great

Comment: that's the editor, it says nothing about your tex system, in particular the version of pdftex.def (which would have to be 10 or so years old  think not to support eps)

Comment: How can I know the version/ upgrade my pdftex.def?

Comment: your miktex installation is a bit old you should probably update it, however thought it should have worked in 2011, simplest is to just save the eps file as .png or .pdf or add \pagestyle{plain} or you could add `\usepackage{epstopdf}` and see if that forces miktex to trigger the conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example runs without error in texlive 2016, If I add `\listfiles` to your example it shows the following in the log

```
 *File List*
    amcs.cls    2016/05/06
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   times.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
 amsmath.sty    2016/06/28 v2.15d AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
caption2.sty    2015/09/15 v2.2-100 Customising captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
   color.sty    2016/07/10 v1.1e Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 harvard.sty    
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
algorithm.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environm
ent
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
algorithmic.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithmic'
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
logol-eps-converted-to.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
 ***********
```

Check the versions in your log. For really old tex installations (possibly as old as last century) you need to convert the logol.eps to logol.png or logol.pdf using (for example) eps2pdf) before running pdftex.

---

Or add `\pagestyle{plain}` so it doesn't try to include the image.

Comment: Thanks. I added the log file. Can you help me?